# Bash script - Is there a way to read what is being logged in console?

Tags: bash, automation

I'm using a web API and when it crashes I have to manually restart it by clearing the current command and then typing 'npm start' into the console. To save myself some trouble I tried writing a bash script to execute this command automatically, this is what it looks like:

```
npm start
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
    npm start
done
```

However, this isn't working as I expected because when the API crashes the command doesn't exit, and therefore there is no exit code.

When the API crashes it logs this in the terminal:

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is it possible for me to read this console log in the bash script somehow, and automatically trigger the appropriate commands to restart it?

Comment: Don't use nodemon to run this app if you don't want this feature.

Comment: Hi @tkausl thank you for answering. How would I run it without using nodemon?